# Deleting 'foreign key' relationships in CosmosDB?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using CosmosDB as a document database, for some things I have to store a 'foreign key' link and the way I've been doing it is as a string property on a document pointing at the ID of the 'foreign key' document.

If the foreign document is deleted what would the most efficient way be of finding all foreign key links and ensuring they are removed?

I'd like it to be as automated as possible so I don't have to 'think' about it too hard in a project, my best solution in my head is to store foreign key links in a well defined structure like:

```
{
"foreignId": "crazy_person",
"foreignType": "person"
}
```

And store that structure in any way shape or form across various documents, then when "crazy_person" is deleted I find all documents which have that structure defined and if the foreignId/foreignType matches crazy_person to remove them.

Not sure how I would implement this though as the structure above could be in any given document, like so:

```
{
   "foreignPerson": {
     "foreignId": "crazy_person",
     "foreignType": "person"   
},
    "foreignPeople": [
{
"foreignId": "crazy_person",
"foreignType": "person"
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is **NO** [Foreign Key concept](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/modeling-data#what-about-foreign-keys) in CosmosDB. According to the docs,

> any inter-document relationships that you have in documents are
>   effectively "weak links" and will not be verified by the database
>   itself. If you want to ensure that the data a document is referring to
>   actually exists, then you need to do this in your application, or
>   through the use of server-side triggers or stored procedures on Azure
>   Cosmos DB.